# Macbook Pro 13 early 2015, Internal ssd not recognized

Tags: macbook-pro, ssd

I have a problem seeing the internal sdd, I have it unplugged currently because if i plug it in it gets very hot in less than a minute. I bought an external T5 ssd and used the recovery option to install ios and it works fine. is there an external adapter to plug the apple ssd, so i can see if the fault is from the ssd or the logic board?

Comment: Those are PCIe SSDs (not standard SATAs).  There are [USB enclosures](https://amzn.to/2JY88Mv) available, but they are awfully expensive.   Getting "hot" is "normal", the question is "how hot."  The Mac has sensors that will shut it down if it exceeds a particular threshold.  I would install it and then issue the command `diskutil list` to see if it shows up.

Comment: it gets very hot once i plug it in. my fingers get burnt if i touch it, I also had it installed in but it doesn't show up in diskutil

Comment: The SSD is *probably* dead, but let's confirm.  One last thing you can do is install it, boot your recovery and issue the command `system_profiler SPStorageDataType` to see if it's detected at all.  Post your output to your question so we can take a look.